# Нужно придумать формулу роста цены

Tags: математика

Нужно придумать 2 формулы, одна - будет считать количество монет, другая - окончательную цену после покупки. Но суть такова. У пользователя есть к примеру 1000 баксов, цена одной монеты 100 баксов. И когда он хочет купить монет на 1000 баксов, то должно происходить следующее. При покупке первой монеты, цена должна быть 100 (то-есть начальная) но когда он покупает 2 монету то цена уже должна быть 101 бакса, на третей монете 102 бакса и так до тех пор пока он не потратит все деньги.

---

Циклом решить можно в программе- но там цикл не подходит никак. Не спрашивайте почему просто никак. Нужно именно формулы и только так.

---

По сути оно должно выглядит так:

1. столбец - количество единиц(денег) игрока
2. столбец - количество монет
3. столбец - цена

---

- 1000 - 0   - 100
- 900  - 1   - 101
- 799  - 2   - 102
- 697  - 3  - 103
- 594  - 4   - 104
- 490  - 5   - 105
- 385  - 6   - 106
- 279  - 7   - 107
- 172  - 8   - 108
- 64   - 9   - 109
- 0   - 9,58 - 109,58

---

Но еще нюанс таков, что единица в программе считаеться как 1е18. Тоесть 1000 баксов это 1000е18 и так дальше. Програма не работает с точкой, только целые числа. Если при расчетах будет числа после точки то она все эти числа выкинет и только целое число выдаст при расчетах, поэтому единица это 1е18.
Помогите придумать формулы.

---

Так же нужна и обратная формула падения цены и уменьшения монет - типа пользователь продал все свои монеты!

---

Входные данные

1. Текущая цена монеты
2. Количество денег на которые пользователь готов купить монет!(при покупке)
3. Количество монет которые пользователь хочет продать(для обратной
   формулы при продаже монет)

Comment: У формулы всегда есть входные данные. Какие входные данные вы предполагаете у этих двух формул?

Comment: Входные данные это текущая цена монеты, и количество денег , на которые пользователь готов купить монет.

Comment: Вы что-нибудь слышали о сумме арифметической прогрессии?

Comment: Арифметическую прогрессию в 9 классе изучал?

Comment: Нет поэтому и прошу помочь.

Comment: @VitaliMalinovski Tеперь Вы знаете слова для поиска и изучения.

Comment: Понял. Но если использовать формулу последний член арифметической прогрессии деленный на суму прогрессии то при 1000 доларах павельный результат, а при 2000 доларах уже идет расхождение.